# How can I create a custom calendar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I want to create a custom calendar, like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code?

Comment: no i havent tried anything yet, i dont even have any idea to start

Comment: Check Tabbar and GridView widgets. I also recommend you to check  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Flutter Table Calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar)

Fully Customisable as per requirement

Answer (score 14):

[image]

You can design your own custom Calendar Widget as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalendarState createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now(); // TO tracking date

  int currentDateSelectedIndex = 0; //For Horizontal Date
  ScrollController scrollController =
      ScrollController(); //To Track Scroll of ListView

  List<String> listOfMonths = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];

  List<String> listOfDays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('My Calendar'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //To Show Current Date
          Container(
              height: 30,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                selectedDate.day.toString() +
                    '-' +
                    listOfMonths[selectedDate.month - 1] +
                    ', ' +
                    selectedDate.year.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    color: Colors.indigo[700]),
              )),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          //To show Calendar Widget
          Container(
              height: 80,
              child: Container(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SizedBox(width: 10);
                },
                itemCount: 365,
                controller: scrollController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentDateSelectedIndex = index;
                        selectedDate =
                            DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index));
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 60,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey[400],
                                offset: Offset(3, 3),
                                blurRadius: 5)
                          ],
                          color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                              ? Colors.black
                              : Colors.white),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            listOfMonths[DateTime.now()
                                        .add(Duration(days: index))
                                        .month -
                                    1]
                                .toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            DateTime.now()
                                .add(Duration(days: index))
                                .day
                                .toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            listOfDays[DateTime.now()
                                        .add(Duration(days: index))
                                        .weekday -
                                    1]
                                .toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: currentDateSelectedIndex == index
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ))),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: this is very useful for me really thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can reference source code of package https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_timeline or directly use it

code snippet

```
CalendarTimeline(
              initialDate: DateTime(2020, 2, 20),
              firstDate: DateTime(2020, 2, 15),
              lastDate: DateTime(2021, 11, 20),
              onDateSelected: (date) => print(date),
              leftMargin: 20,
              monthColor: Colors.white70,
              dayColor: Colors.teal[200],
              //dayNameColor: Color(0xFF333A47),
              activeDayColor: Colors.white,
              activeBackgroundDayColor: Colors.redAccent[100],
              dotsColor: Color(0xFF333A47),
              selectableDayPredicate: (date) => date.day != 23,
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:calendar_timeline/calendar_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF333A47),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Text(
                'Calendar Timeline',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.copyWith(color: Colors.tealAccent[100]),
              ),
            ),
            CalendarTimeline(
              initialDate: DateTime(2020, 2, 20),
              firstDate: DateTime(2020, 2, 15),
              lastDate: DateTime(2021, 11, 20),
              onDateSelected: (date) => print(date),
              leftMargin: 20,
              monthColor: Colors.white70,
              dayColor: Colors.teal[200],
              //dayNameColor: Color(0xFF333A47),
              activeDayColor: Colors.white,
              activeBackgroundDayColor: Colors.redAccent[100],
              dotsColor: Color(0xFF333A47),
              selectableDayPredicate: (date) => date.day != 23,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend: [SFCalendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar)
The SyncFusion team has made an enormous amount of highly customizable and nice-looking widgets, this being just one of them.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.